# Can see my files through Save File dialog but not through Windows Explorer on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

I'm downloading some files through a program called Metatrader and trying to save it with the Save File dialog under a sub-directory of the software (in Program Files), but under Windows Explorer I can't see the files.

Where did Windows 7 store them?

Answer (score 5):

The files that you downloaded were virtualized. To view them in explorer you have to click Compatibility Files button that appears on the explorer bar. This button only appears in directories that contain virtualized files.

Windows virtualizes files saved to Program Files (and some other directories) in certain programs for compatibility issues. Click here to read more: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927387

Comment: I had no idea Windows did that until reading this post. Very helpful! I pulling [what remains of] my hair out trying to find a file I just saved.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue with the print (& save to file) dialog box in IE. I could see the file in the dialog box, but not thru windows explorer.

I could finally locate the file at this location:

C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Virtualized\C\Users\username\Documents\

I got to know the exact location by opening up the file in the dialog box thru my text editor. I then went to that location in windows explorer and "rescued" the files off to where I wanted them originally.

Comment: Thanks! That was a good start for my problem. Here's more information that I needed: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927387

Answer (score 0):

The software might not be saving the files actually, because saving to Program Files requires UAC elevation (unless you have UAC disabled). Are you running metatrader as an Administrator?

Also try enabling the display of hidden files and system files by going to Folder options.

Comment: Yes it is saving because I've done so for 3 days so I can see all the past files I already saved there through file dialog but I didn't realize until today I could not use them outside of metatrader :)

No I didn't launch as administrator.

Comment: I'm new to windows 7, I can't see any option for unhiding files in folder properties ?

What I've is that I zipped under file dialog that's how I did get my files !

Comment: http://i43.tinypic.com/2lkwr3q.png and http://i40.tinypic.com/jfaozt.png

Select "Show hidden files, folders and drives" and uncheck "Hide protected operating system files" (although the latter may not help at all, but worth a try)